# Android studio не находит (не создаёт) R.java файл (его просто нет) на xubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, xubuntu

Добрый день! Установил студию на `xubuntu`. Студия ругается на `R.java файл`  в любом проекте, неважно  новый это проект или старый импортированный. В папках с  проектами папки `r` тоже нет,  видимо, андроид студия их не создаёт. `Clean  project` и `Rebuild` не помогают, версия `buildTools 25.0.3`, если это имеет  значение.

Ниже скриншот содержимого папки нового проекта (обрезать не смог, прошу прощения. Не разобрался ещё как работать с gimp). Папки `r` и, соответственно,  файла `R.java` там, где она должна быть, нет. Как это можно исправить?

UPD. Версия java :

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alexeyy.fdfkjdskjfkdsn"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[image: Папка с проектом]

Comment: Покажите свой `build.gradle` и версию Java

Comment: @Barmaley добавил в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте без Студии - запустить `shell/terminal` и запустить оттуда `gradle` - собирается или нет?

Comment: @Barmaley запустил `gradle`, собрался - `BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.402 secs
`

Comment: @Barmaley запустил `gradle` в папке проекта, `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/javir/AndroidStudioProjects/Fdfkjdskjfkdsn/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.10. ` Надо обновить gradle, я правильно понял?

Comment: @Barmaley обновил `gradle`, теперь собирает в терминале - `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, но в Андроид студии по-прежнему ругается на R.

Comment: Это значит, что в Студии что-то не так. Попробуйте clear-cache и заново запуститься + проверьте путь к Android SDK

Comment: @Barmaley clear-cache не помогает, путь к SDK правильный

Comment: А вы правильно то установили Студию на убунту? Какая версия стоит? В настройках показывает на gradle или на gradle-wrapper?

Comment: @Barmaley в настройках стоит `Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`. Версия студии 2.2.2, полгода назад установил, проблемы возникли ещё тогда.

Comment: Сносите нафик 2.2.2 и установите хотя бы 2.3
Далее установите нормальный gradle хотя бы 3.х и пропишите путь к нему напрямую, без gradle-wrapper

Comment: Вообще в ubuntu студия работает намного лучше, быстрее и стабильнее чем под виндой - эмулятор просто летает, так что не пожалейте времени на ее правильную настройку

Comment: @Barmaley видимо, придётся сносить. А можно это сделать без удаления sdk и прочего? Только студию? И как правильно её удалить и установить, чтобы не было больше проблем? Боюсь опять накосячить

Comment: Конечно можно... просто можно удалить каталог `~/android-studio` и его последышей типа ~/.android

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59985/discussion-between-alexeyy-and-barmaley).

Comment: Удалил `xubuntu`, установил `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` и `Android studio` с нуля, всё равно та же проблема - не генерируется файл `R.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему просто создав пустой класс `R` в папке с `MainActivity.class`.  Может поможет кому-нибудь в подобной ситуации.

```
package com.example.alexeyy.myapplication;

class R {
}
```